# Using Facebook Login with my OAuth2 API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an API which uses OAuth2 for authentication. This works fine, I can use the 'Password' Grant Type to let users obtain an access token using their username and password stored in my app.

Now things get a little tricky. I want to have an iOS app which can talk to this API. No problems, users can provide me with their username and password and I can provide them with an access token.

But I want to be able to use Facebook Login to allow users to register and login to my API.

My questions are:

1. As far as I can tell, the iOS SDK for Facebook will provide me with an access token and the user's profile ID. What do I do with this information? How should this information be stored, along with regular 'username and password' users?
2. What is the login flow between the iOS App and my server, from the user logging in to Facebook on their iOS device and them getting an access token to my API?

Language inspecific answers would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What about:

1. Obtain FB-AT and FB-ID in client (in app with SSO or through redirected web view)
2. Request YOURAPI-AT from YOURAPI-AuthenticationServer with FB-ID and FB-AT
3. YOURAPI-AuthenticationServer checks validity of FB-ID and FB-AT against FB-AuthenticationServer
4. If OK, YOURAPI-AuthenticationServer returns a YOURAPI-AT (and optionally the YOURAPI-RefreshToken)

Now you can use the YOURAPI-AT to access your API :) and optionally the YOURAPI-RT to refresh the AT, so you don't need to go to FB all the time.

Comment: That sounds good, but it would be a custom grant type. I guess that's OK, because OAuth2 was never meant to solve this problem, and I could still have the other grant types (implicit etc) available for 3rd party developers to access my API on behalf of another user.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the OAuth2 flow to support account association, so you would have to build this yourself.

You would have to login to FB, obtain a token from them, call the userinfo endpoint and then store users information in your database so a specific user in FB corresponds with a user in your account database.

The most elegant way of solving this is to create an intermediary service that bridges your user account database and FB, so your app interacts with just one service:

```
Your app -> Identity Service -+-> Your user account
                              |
                              +-> FB
```

This is a lot of work though (I know because this is essentially what we've built, and it is not trivial).

In any case, your API will likely have to continue using your tokens.

Here's [the article we wrote on account linking](https://docs.auth0.com/link-accounts) that might inspire you to implement something similar. But, as I said, this is custom, not part of the protocol.

Comment: OK that makes sense. What sort of OAuth Grant Type should I use to authenticate against my API for a Facebook user?

Comment: I think FB only supports authZ code flow and implicit. If the server is the one handling the authN you can use authZ code (as you can safely store secrets in your backend). If it is all client driven, you 're probably better off with the implicit flow.